# query length of request longer then maxQueryLength value when redirecting to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, authentication, webforms

I was trying to redirect to login page if user wasn't logged in with this code in *web.config* in `system.web` section

```
</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH"
           slidingExpiration="true"  />
</authentication>
```

But when I open it in a browser, I get the error *query length of request longer then maxquerylength value*.

I tried to add this to *web.config* in `system.webserver` section

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" >
      </requestLimits>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

but it didn't work, anyone can help me? (the url lenght is 2091)

Comment: can you try this: <requestLimits maxQueryString="3000" maxUrl="3000" />. You should keep in mind, that allowing long query string and url is a security risk

Comment: @alaa_sayegh i know that is a security risk but the url generated is full of numbers like 2 and 5, i don't know why it's so long, your tip solved my problem but now it says that page is not working because i've done too much request, any tip (timeout = 60 didn't work)

Comment: ok, let me add my tip as an answer and it will be great if you could mark it as an answer :). and let us look after the new issue!

Comment: I guess you are having an infinite loop of requests. It is calling the login page again and again. Can you share please your code and your URL?

Comment: @alaa_sayegh code posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:
you need to add this to web.config in system.web section

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />

</authorization>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="60"/>
</authentication>
```

then add this above the configuration end tag:

```
  <location path="Account">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
<location path="Account/Login">
  <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Up this answer, it's the solution @alaa_sayegh ty for the help :D

Answer (score 1):

it is exactly an infinite loop issue. you are redirecting continuously to the login page. Response.Redirect("Login.aspx") or Response.Redirect("Account/Login.aspx") should be the statement that is being called.Are you calling this statment anywhere? In the Default.aspx maybe?

Answer (score 0):

web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>

    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=server\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=aspnet-Project1-20171011010223; uid; pwd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />

    </authorization>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" timeout="60"/>
    </authentication>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" maxQueryStringLength="30000" />
    <pages enableEventValidation="true" enableViewState="true">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity" />
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
      </controls>
    </pages>

    <sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
      </providers>
    </sessionState>
    <httpModules>

      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxQueryString="30000" maxUrl="30000" >
          </requestLimits>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
      <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="EntityFramework" publicKeyToken="b77a5c561934e089" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

</configuration>
```

Apparati.aspx - default page (here if users isn't logged it'll be redirected to Login.aspx)

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" >
    <div class="container" style="padding:10px;background-color:#c4d7f2">
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnAggiungi" OnClick="btnAggiungi_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/add.png" />
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnModifica" OnClick="btnModifica_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"/>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnRipristina" OnClick="btnRipristina_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/cancel.png"/>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnCancella" OnClick="btnCancella_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/delete.png" OnClientClick="if (!confirm('Vuoi cancellare il record?')) return false;"/>
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnSalva" OnClick="btnSalva_Click" ImageUrl="~/Images/update.png" Visible="false"/>
    </div>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnApparati" runat="server" Height="500" ScrollBars="Auto" CssClass="panel panel-primary">
   <asp:GridView CssClass="table table-bordered table-hover" runat="server" ID="grvApparati" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="grvApparati_SelectedIndexChanged">
       <Columns>

           <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" ReadOnly="true"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c1" HeaderText="Tipo" SortExpression="Tipo" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c2" HeaderText="Modello" SortExpression="Modello" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c3" HeaderText="Descrizione" SortExpression="Descrizione" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c4" HeaderText="IP Lan" SortExpression="IP Lan" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c5" HeaderText="IP Pubblico" SortExpression="IP Pubblico" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c6" HeaderText="Porta" SortExpression="Porta" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c7" HeaderText="Rete Ass." SortExpression="Rete Ass." />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c8" HeaderText="User" SortExpression="User" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c9" HeaderText="Password" SortExpression="Password"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c10" HeaderText="IP 1" SortExpression="IP 1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c11" HeaderText="IP 2" SortExpression="IP 2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c12" HeaderText="Wan 1" SortExpression="Wan 1" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c13" HeaderText="Wan 2" SortExpression="Wan 2" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="c14" HeaderText="Wan 3" SortExpression="Wan 3" />
       </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
        </asp:Panel>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Content>
```

Apparati.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : Page
  {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlDataAdapter dad;
        DataSet ds;
        string SqlQuery = "";
        string cliente;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["cliente"] != null)
            {
                cliente = Session["cliente"].ToString();
            }
            else
                cliente="";
            con = new SqlConnection(Globals.strConnection);
            SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Tab1 WHERE c15 = '" + cliente + "'";
            dad = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            con.Open();
            dad.Fill(ds);
            con.Close();
            for (int c = 0; c < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; c++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    ds.Tables[0].Rows[c][i] = EncryptD.Decrypt(ds.Tables[0].Rows[c][i].ToString());
                }
            }
            grvApparati.DataSource = ds;
            if (!IsPostBack)
                grvApparati.DataBind();
            for (int c = 0; c < grvApparati.Rows.Count;c++)
            {
                grvApparati.Rows[c].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(grvApparati, "Select$" + c); 
            }
            if (Session["editindex"] != null)
            {
                grvApparati.EditIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["editindex"]);
                grvApparati.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["editindex"]);
                DataBind();
                Session["editindex"] = null;
                btnSalva.Visible = true;
            }
        }


        protected void btnAggiungi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int id;
            DataSet tmpds = new DataSet();
            SqlQuery = "SELECT MAX(ID) FROM Tab1 ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
            con.Open();
            dad = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlQuery, con);
            dad.Fill(tmpds);
            if (tmpds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString() == "")
                id = 1;
            else
                id = Convert.ToInt32(tmpds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0]) + 1;
            SqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Tab1 (ID, c15) VALUES (" + id + ", '" + cliente + "')";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Session["editindex"] = grvApparati.Rows.Count;
            Response.Redirect("/Apparati.aspx");
        }
        protected void grvApparati_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            grvApparati.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;

            DataBind();
        }



        protected void btnModifica_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            grvApparati.EditIndex = grvApparati.SelectedIndex;
            btnSalva.Visible = true;
            DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnRipristina_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            grvApparati.EditIndex = -1;
            Response.Redirect("/Apparati.aspx");
        }



        protected void grvApparati_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grvApparati.Rows)
            {
                if (row.RowIndex == grvApparati.SelectedIndex)
                {
                    row.Style.Value = "background:#dbe8f9;";
                }
                else
                {
                    row.Style.Value = "background:white;";
                }
            }
        }



        protected void btnCancella_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(grvApparati.DataKeys[grvApparati.SelectedIndex].Value.ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlQuery = "DELETE FROM Tab1 WHERE ID = " + id;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Redirect("/Apparati.aspx");
        }

        protected void btnSalva_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(grvApparati.DataKeys[grvApparati.EditIndex].Value.ToString());
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)grvApparati.Rows[grvApparati.EditIndex];
            TextBox c1 = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];
            TextBox c2 = (TextBox)row.Cells[3].Controls[0];
            TextBox c3 = (TextBox)row.Cells[4].Controls[0];
            TextBox c4 = (TextBox)row.Cells[5].Controls[0];
            TextBox c5 = (TextBox)row.Cells[6].Controls[0];
            TextBox c6 = (TextBox)row.Cells[7].Controls[0];
            TextBox c7 = (TextBox)row.Cells[8].Controls[0];
            TextBox c8 = (TextBox)row.Cells[9].Controls[0];
            TextBox c9 = (TextBox)row.Cells[10].Controls[0];
            TextBox c10 = (TextBox)row.Cells[11].Controls[0];
            TextBox c11 = (TextBox)row.Cells[12].Controls[0];
            TextBox c12 = (TextBox)row.Cells[13].Controls[0];
            TextBox c13 = (TextBox)row.Cells[14].Controls[0];
            TextBox c14 = (TextBox)row.Cells[15].Controls[0];

            con.Open();
            SqlQuery = "UPDATE Tab1 SET c1 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c1.Text) + "', " +
                "c2 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c2.Text) + "', " +
                "c3 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c3.Text) + "', " +
                "c4 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c4.Text) + "', " +
                "c5 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c5.Text) + "', " +
                "c6 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c6.Text) + "', " +
                "c7 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c7.Text) + "', " +
                "c8 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c8.Text) + "', " +
                "c9 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c9.Text) + "', " +
                "c10 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c10.Text) + "', " +
                "c11 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c11.Text) + "', " +
                "c12 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c12.Text) + "', " +
                "c13 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c13.Text) + "', " +
                "c14 = '" + EncryptD.Encrypt(c14.Text) + "', " +
                "c15 = '" + cliente + "' WHERE ID = " + id;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, con);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            grvApparati.EditIndex = -1;
            DataBind();
            Response.Redirect("/Apparati.aspx");

        }
```

you need master page and login page?

Comment: thanks for the code. I guess you are redirecting to the login page on the master page, right? Let me see that code behind for the master page and the login page

Comment: @alaa_sayegh i've added web.config reported in the question to redirect,  master code in the answers

Comment: i don't see the master page code, it is only the code from the Apparati.aspx + web.config. Yes you are redirecting in the web.config to login, but i want to see if you are doing any redirections in the master & login code behind. Can you please paste the exception that you are getting regadring the too much requests as well?

Comment: @alaa_sayegh look the last 2 answers

Comment: it is exactly an infinite loop issue. you are redirecting continuously to the login page. Response.Redirect("Login.aspx") or Response.Redirect("Account/Login.aspx") should be the statement that is being called.Are you calling this statment anywhere? In the Default.aspx maybe?

Comment: @alaa_sayegh oh wait i'm redirecting "?" users to login page in every page, login page too, this is the problem, how can i allow access to login page only?? (post your last comment as answer+) <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
      
    </authorization>

Comment: i added it as answer.

Comment: see this: <authorization>
  <deny users ="?" />
  <allow users = "*" />
</authorization>

Comment: and i think when you solve this, then you dont need anymore the maxUrl="3000" attribute anymore. because this long URL is happening only because of too many redirects

Answer (score 0):

Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Project1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="it">

<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Applicazione ASP.NET</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

                <link href="/Content/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>

<body>
    <form runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>

                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />

            </Scripts>

        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <script src="/Scripts/select2.min.js" ></script>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand"  runat="server">TMC Cred.</a>
                </div>
                <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                    <div class="from-group" style="display:inline-block;padding:10px;width:70%" >
                    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="drlClienti" DataTextField="an_descr1" ClientIDMode="Static" 
     DataValueField="an_conto" DataSourceId="dsClienti" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drlClienti_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" OnDataBound="drlClienti_DataBound">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#" + "<%=drlClienti.ClientID%>").select2({
                placeholder: "Seleziona un cliente",
                allowClear: true,

            });
        });
    </script>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsClienti" ConnectionString="Server=server;Database=CREDTMC;UID=uid;pwd=pwd;LANGUAGE=us_english" runat="server" SelectCommandType="Text" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM pers_view_clienti WHERE an_tipo = 'C' ORDER BY an_descr1"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                        </div>

                    <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                        <AnonymousTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login" title="Login">Accedi</a></li>
                              <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register" title="Register">Registrati</a></li>  
                            </ul>
                        </AnonymousTemplate>
                        <LoggedInTemplate>
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                             <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Ciao, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %> </a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu
                          <span class="caret"></span></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="/Apparati.aspx">Dati clienti</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Dati interni</a></li>
                                                            <li>
                                    <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Disconnetti" LogoutPageUrl="/Account/Login.aspx" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                                </li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                            </ul>
                        </LoggedInTemplate>
                    </asp:LoginView>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-inverse " style="height:auto" >
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar " >
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li ><a runat="server" href="/Apparati.aspx" >Apparati</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About" >Credenziali SQL</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact" >Account posta</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About" >Gruppo aziende</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About" >Laboratorio</a></li>
                        <li><a runat="server" href="~/About" >VKI</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container body-content">

            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>&copy; <%: DateTime.Now.Year %> - Team Memores Computer S.p.a.</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Site.Master.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

namespace Project1
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        private const string AntiXsrfTokenKey = "__AntiXsrfToken";
        private const string AntiXsrfUserNameKey = "__AntiXsrfUserName";
        private string _antiXsrfTokenValue;

        protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Il codice seguente facilita la protezione da attacchi XSRF
            var requestCookie = Request.Cookies[AntiXsrfTokenKey];
            Guid requestCookieGuidValue;
            if (requestCookie != null && Guid.TryParse(requestCookie.Value, out requestCookieGuidValue))
            {
                // Utilizzare il token Anti-XSRF dal cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = requestCookie.Value;
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Generare un nuovo token Anti-XSRF e salvarlo nel cookie
                _antiXsrfTokenValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                Page.ViewStateUserKey = _antiXsrfTokenValue;

                var responseCookie = new HttpCookie(AntiXsrfTokenKey)
                {
                    HttpOnly = true,
                    Value = _antiXsrfTokenValue
                };
                if (FormsAuthentication.RequireSSL && Request.IsSecureConnection)
                {
                    responseCookie.Secure = true;
                }
                Response.Cookies.Set(responseCookie);
            }

            Page.PreLoad += master_Page_PreLoad;
        }

        protected void master_Page_PreLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                // Impostare il token Anti-XSRF
                ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] = Page.ViewStateUserKey;
                ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] = Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                // Convalidare il token Anti-XSRF
                if ((string)ViewState[AntiXsrfTokenKey] != _antiXsrfTokenValue
                    || (string)ViewState[AntiXsrfUserNameKey] != (Context.User.Identity.Name ?? String.Empty))
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Convalida del token Anti-XSRF non riuscita.");
                }
            }
        }
        public void ClearSelectionClienti()
        {
            drlClienti.ClearSelection();
        }
        protected void Unnamed_LoggingOut(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            Session["gruppo"] = null;
            Response.Redirect("/Account/Login.aspx");
        }

        protected void drlClienti_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (drlClienti.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                Session["cliente"] = drlClienti.SelectedValue.ToString();
                Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
            }
        }

        protected void drlClienti_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["cliente"] != null)
            {
                drlClienti.SelectedValue = Session["cliente"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                drlClienti.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(string.Empty, string.Empty));
                drlClienti.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

P.S. there are some junk methods, just ignore them :D

Answer (score 0):

URL: http://localhost:55920/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FAccount%2FLogin%3FReturnUrl%3D%252FAccount%252FLogin%253FReturnUrl%253D%25252FAccount%25252FLogin%25253FReturnUrl%25253D%2525252FAccount%2525252FLogin%2525253FReturnUrl%2525253D%252525252FAccount%252525252FLogin%252525253FReturnUrl%252525253D%25252525252FAccount%25252525252FLogin%25252525253FReturnUrl%25252525253D%2525252525252FAccount%2525252525252FLogin%2525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525253D%252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252FLogin%252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525253D%25252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525253D%2525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252FAccount%25252525252525252525252525252FLogin%25252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%25252525252525252525252525253D%2525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%2525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%2525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%2525252525252525252525252525253D%252525252525252525252525252525252FAccount%252525252525252525252525252525252FLogin%252525252525252525252525252525253FReturnUrl%252525252525252525252525252525253D%25252525252525252525252525252525252fApparati

Error Screen:
[Page not working local host had redirected you too much times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGZDv.png)

the master page code is in the answer above